# How to bind two classes into one classes using google guice?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, guice

I'v a base class which has selenium configuration for the application. I want to use the class A(selenium configuration.class) to another class B(Action.class) which is again has to extend Class c(UIElemnts.class).
I tried to user Google guice to bind the classes like this.

- how should I use two classes (A& C) on class B using Google Guice. Kindly explain with example

In this example I want to use the setup method and driver object in class B but class B is already extended to Class. I just want to try Google Guice to bind the classes.

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.ProxyType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import test.com.x.software.b.base.SeleniumConfiguration;

import com.google.inject.Binder;
import com.google.inject.Module;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;

public class SeleniumConfiguration extends SeleneseTestBase{

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public static void setup() {

        // Invoking firefox browser
        FirefoxProfile firefoxobj = new FirefoxProfile();
        firefoxobj.setPreference("network.proxy.type",
                ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());
        // System.out.println("********************");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxobj);
        // System.out.println("********************"+Url);
        driver.navigate().to("https://software.x.com");
        // System.out.println("********************");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }




}
```

---

```
public class class B extends Class C{


    @ Test
    public static void createDeveloper() throws InterruptedException
    {

//  String currentdate=dateFormatting();
//  String firstname="Test_Fn_"+currentdate;
//  String lastname ="Test_Ln_"+currentdate;
//  String loginid="Test_Tp_"+currentdate;


}
```

---

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Class C extends PageFactory {
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you mean. Where is your Injector? What is an ISingleton?

Comment: @JanGalinski, I've modified the code. I copied the code which I was trying out and it was a mess. I've edited it now. I'd like to know how to use the Class A and C methods and ojects in class B using Google guice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what problem you are trying to solve. If you have class B and want to use the methods of two different classes (A and C) in class B, then it looks like you just need to declare the dependency of class B on class A and C and then either delegate public methods to the underlying class A and C or use the methods internally in class B.  Here is a SSCE:

```
public class SO24278992 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            // Different concrete instances of A and C
            // could be used here.  
            //
            // Alternatively, you don't need these explicit
            // bindings at all if the default contstructor
            // does everything you need and you are not 
            // requiring explicit bindings.

            bind(A.class).toInstance(new A());
            bind(C.class).toInstance(new C());

        }
    });

    B b = injector.getInstance(B.class);
    b.useA();
    b.useC();

}


static class B {

    private A classA;
    private C classC;

    @Inject
    public B(A a, C c) {
        this.classA = a;
        this.classC = c;
    }

    public void useC() {
        classC.doSomething();
    }

    public void useA() {
        classA.doSomethingElse();

    }
}


static class A {

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println("Doing something else in A");
    }

}

static class C {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something in C");
    }

}
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you are talking about though.

- chooks

Comment: I was looking at testng documentation where in they mentioned some thing like this. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html under (5.18.2 - Guice dependency injection). anyways this answered to my question, but still want to know how they used that.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to implement something like the below one.not sure how did they implement it.
(http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

```
5.18.2 - Guice dependency injection

If you use Guice, TestNG gives you an easy way to inject your test objects with a Guice module:
@Guice(modules = GuiceExampleModule.class)
public class GuiceTest extends SimpleBaseTest {

  @Inject
  ISingleton m_singleton;

  @Test
  public void singletonShouldWork() {
    m_singleton.doSomething();
  }

}
In this example, GuiceExampleModule is expected to bind the interface ISingleton to some concrete class:
public class GuiceExampleModule implements Module {

  @Override
  public void configure(Binder binder) {
    binder.bind(ISingleton.class).to(ExampleSingleton.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }

}
```

*Refernce: Copied from testng.org*